# Remove unneeded files from /lib/firmware

Tags: hardware, disk-usage, firmware

I'm trying to clear up space on my root partition and /lib/firmware is taking up a lot of space.  There are a lot of files for devices that I know I don't have, but there's also a lot of files for devices that I don't recognize so I don't know whether or not I need the firmware.

Is there maybe a way to see what firmware files have actually been loaded?

Comment: how are we suppose to know what you have installed, what hardware you have and what -you- installed as firmware and do not need? afaik in /lib/firmware anything in there is needed. what does `du -ks /lib/firmware` show?  and please edit the question with the info instead of commenting.

Comment: Don't touch /lib/firmware. If you're trying to clear up space on your root partition, look elsewhere... like removing older unused kernels, or /var/crash crash logs, or /var/log/ log files.

Comment: Or /var/cache :P

Comment: I know there's other places to look to clear up space, but I'm still curious about this.  There's definitely a lot of files in /lib/firmware I don't need and besides, it seems like there should be at least a log somewhere of what files have been loaded.

Comment: Worth an experiment! If you have a live Linux USB stick that you know works then you could just try moving all the files you don't recognise (to eg /home/user/fw), reboot and see what happens! `lsof`(maybe piped through grep) will tell you if "lib/firmware" file handles are currently open; diff the list with the directory, etc.. Seems like it would work. If your filesystem has "atime" that would help too. Use the USB stick to move files back if it doesn't reboot.

Comment: @pbhj I was going to do that but I didn't want to have to reboot.  Next time I do though I'll try to and narrow down what's actually needed and what's not.

Still seems weird though that the kernel has no way of telling users what firmware has been loaded.

Comment: FWIW my `du -c /lib/firmware/` is 300M. You'd have to be really tight on space to not be able to afford that, even if it's all wasted. `\du -c -d2 /lib/firmware/ | sort -n | tail` shows me that liquidio is my largest wasted folder and that's only 24M.

Comment: @alex "There's definitely a lot of files in /lib/firmware I don't need" You can claim all you want but please proof it. Match every file with what you see online and investigate. 95% of MY /lib/firmware is related to videocard, nic, wireless, BT, USB and internal hardware.  Oh and removing /lib/firmware needs to be done by uninstalling the corresponding driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bite here: I agree that there is potentially a lot of files in `/lib/firmware` that you might not need, and as such it should be possible to remove some of it.

However, in any case this should be done with caution, and you should be prepared to put back the missing firmware files via a live USB boot or similar method.

I've made the following list of the foldes in `/lib/firmware` that are over 5 MB, just for starters: *(I've removed `intel` and `intel-ucode`, since you most likely shouldn't remove these)*

> ```
> /lib/firmware/netronome       : NIC firmware implementation for Agilio SmartNICs
> /lib/firmware/amdgpu          : AMD GPU firmware
> /lib/firmware/mellanox        : Mellanox Ethernet and InfiniBand NIC firmware
> /lib/firmware/qcom            : Qualcomm device firmware
> /lib/firmware/mrvl            : Marvell device firmware
> /lib/firmware/ath11k          : Firmware for Qualcomm IEEE 802.11ax devices
> /lib/firmware/i915            : Firmware for i915 Intel GFX Driver
> /lib/firmware/liquidio        : NIC firmware implementation for Marvell Liquidio SmartNICs
> /lib/firmware/qed             : Firmware for QLogic Everest FastLinQ Linux Driver
> /lib/firmware/mediatek        : MediaTak device firmware
> /lib/firmware/dpaa2           : Firmware for DPAA2 (Data Path Acceleration Architecture Gen2) 
> /lib/firmware/ath10k          : Firmware for Qualcomm IEEE 802.11ac devices
> /lib/firmware/brcm            : Broadcom device firmware
> /lib/firmware/radeon          : Firmware for AMD Radeon GPU adapters
> /lib/firmware/rtw89           : Firmware for Realtek rtw89 devices
> /lib/firmware/cypress         : Cypress device firmware
> /lib/firmware/ti-connectivity : Texas Instruments device firmware
> ```

I would then suggest that you run `sudo lshw`, and thoroughly go through the list. If you're 100% sure that you don't have hardware from a specific vendor, I would say you could *move* that firmware folder. Note that I would suggest you *move* it instead of removing it at first, so that you can put it back in case of any issues.

For instance, I belive video cards are a good example. If you only have an NVidia video card, you could probably remove the AMD GPU firmware - and vice versa. Similarly, for Wireless network adapters, if you have from one vendor, you most likely don't have from any of the other vendors.

Just be aware that if you at a later point decide to change your hardware, you might suddenly miss some of the firmware files. And that's why I (again) would suggest that you don't remove anything, but instead move it to another location.

And finally be aware that when running `sudo apt upgrade`, there could potentially be installed new files inside `/lib/firmware`. So you should probably check periodically for folders that you're absolutely sure you don't need.

Is this an elegant solution? *No.* Is it hacky as hell? *Yes.* However, I would stil argue that there are some cases where files could be removed with no consequence whatsoever. It most certainly is no issue to remove AMD and Nvidia firmware if you're running Ubuntu Server with only an onboard graphics adapter. And there are probably other similar scenarios.

Just be careful, and be prepared to restore files in any case.

*NB: I'm currently investigating a way to reliably find out which firmware files have been accessed since last reboot - I'll report back with this in a couple of days...*

Answer (score -1):

You can check the firmware that is used for your system in the kernel log.

```
grep firmware /var/log/kernel.log
```

will give you a nice list of firmware that was loaded since the last log rotation (could be several days)

However since i first posted this, I learned that most of the firmware will be loaded by initrd and that usually does not generate a logfile of what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's a very reliable method.  The only firmware loading mentioned is for iwlwifi and my Bluetooth card and I know I have at least some intel ucode loaded as well (which is also mentioned in kern.log, but without the 'firmware' string).

Comment: `zgrep firmware /var/log/kern.log.* | cut -d "]" -f 2- | sort | uniq` gives all unique lines from the kernel logs (for me on Kubuntu 18.04.2). But the firmware found there doesn't appear to relate at all to the contents of `/lib/firmware`.

Comment: This isn't really useful at all for identifying which firmware is loaded, sorry..